# Node js refresh browser

Tags: node.js, browser, nodes

I am pretty new to node js...so this question is very basic question....
lets say this is my simple node js code...

```
var http = require('http');
    http.createServer(function(req,res){
        res.writeHead(200,{'content-type':'text/html'});
        res.write('<doctype html><html><body>testing node ...</body></html>');      
        res.end();
    }).listen(8888,'127.0.0.1');


    console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8888');
```

yes it works fine... But let say we make a very small change...if we refresh the browser it does not apply the changes made..

below is my procedure...

1)stop process running on port 8888
2) start node again...
3)refresh the browser...

is this the correct way? everytime we have to do this to apply changes?

Comment: Your description is not clear. What I think waht you want is that when a change done, the server auto restart. If it is, try node module `supervisor`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in your case you should restart application to apply changes. But you can put your HTML code in some html file and send that file to client, then you will not need to restart application if you make changes in html file. Also consider using Express module to serve static files.

Answer (score 1):

Use Supervisor (npm install Supervisor) to automatically restart your server when you make server-side development changes, and use Reload (npm install Reload) to refresh your browser when you make client-side development changes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to Install node nodemon tool

> npm install nodemon --save

and after open cmd and set your project path and run

> nodemon server file
>
> ex.  nodemon server.js

and after you any changes server auto restart....

Answer (score 0):

use code like this:

```
   app.get('/', function (req,res) {
       res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/login.html');
   });
```